# Saving aws S3 image location links to postgres db table

Tags: postgresql, api, amazon-s3, heroku

I have a postgres db via Heroku, with a PUT route to save uploaded s3 bucket image links to the database, however the links are not saving to the database table. There are no errors, I am receiving but the links are simply not saving to the table with the update query I am calling for the db. Can anyone say what could be wrong here?

```
//Here is the table scheme


       CREATE TABLE Users_Channel(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        userID INT UNIQUE,
        FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES Users(id),
        
        channelName varchar(255) UNIQUE,
        FOREIGN KEY(channelName) REFERENCES Users(Username),
 
        Profile_Avatar TEXT NULL,
        Slider_Pic1 TEXT NULL,
        Slider_Pic2 TEXT NULL,
        Slider_Pic3 TEXT NULL,
        Subscriber_Count INT NULL,
        UNIQUE(channelName, userID)
      );


//Database Update Query to updated channel by channel name

async function updateChannel({
  channelname,
  profile_avatar,
  slider_pic1,
  slider_pic2,
  slider_pic3
}) {
  try {
    const { rows } = await client.query(
      `
              UPDATE users_channel
              SET  profile_avatar=$2, slider_pic1=$3, slider_pic2=$4, slider_pic3=$5
              WHERE channelname=$1
              RETURNING *;
            `,
      [channelname, profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3]
    );
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}


//API Put Route

usersRouter.put(
  "/myprofile/update/:channelname",
  profileUpdate,
  requireUser,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const { channelname } = req.params;
    
    
      const pic1 = req.files["avatar"][0];
      const pic2 = req.files["slide1"][0];
      const pic3 = req.files["slide2"][0];
      const pic4 = req.files["slide3"][0];
    
    try {
      const result = await uploadFile(pic1);
      const result1 = await uploadFile(pic2);
      const result2 = await uploadFile(pic3);
      const result3 = await uploadFile(pic4);

      console.log(result, result1, result2, result3);

      const updateData = {
        profile_avatar: result.Location,
        slider_pic1: result1.Location,
        slider_pic2: result2.Location,
        slider_pic3: result3.Location,
      };

      console.log(updateData);
      const updatedchannel = await updateChannel(channelname, updateData);
      res.send({ channel: updatedchannel });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not update user profile", error);
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it had to rework my update query portion to the following below. Took out the curly brackets and created a variable with curly brackets instead and passed it to the function.

```
async function updateChannel(channelname, photos) {
  const { profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3} = photos;
  try {
    const { rows } = await client.query(
      `
              UPDATE users_channel
              SET profile_avatar=$2, slider_pic1=$3, slider_pic2=$4, slider_pic3=$5
              WHERE channelname=$1
              RETURNING *;
            `,
      [channelname, profile_avatar, slider_pic1, slider_pic2, slider_pic3]
    );
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```